# linux - centos won't boot after rebuilding raid

Tags: linux, hard-drive, centos, raid, rescue

I have a dedicated server with OVH. Yesterday they had to replace one of the HDD because it was about to fail.

After replacing the disk, we had to rebuild the RAID and now the server won't boot anymore. The error is "select proper booting device and reboot"

OVH rebooted the server in rescue mode and now i need to find a way to fix the problem...

I use CentOS5

Comment: probably corrupted or wrongly mounted /boot partition